# Log4j failover for kafka appender

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to setup my application to write logs to Kafka using the Log4j's Kafka appender. I have added the kafka client to my classpath and configured kafka appender with relevant configuration.
When Kafka cluster is available, I'm able to receive all the logs.

But if Kafka is down I have to log to a secondary location so that log events are not lost. For that I'm using the FailOver appender, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Below is my full log4j2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="10">
    
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-pattern" value="[%5.-5p]-[%d{UNIX_MILLIS}]-[%-27.-35t]-[%20c{1.}]--- %m%n" />
        <Property name="log-file-location" value="${sys:user.home}/app/logs" />
        <Property name="kafka-server-address" value="localhost:9092" />
        <Property name="kafka-topic-name" value="app-core-logs" />
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <Kafka name="kafka" topic="${kafka-topic-name}">
            <JsonLayout />
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">${kafka-server-address}</Property>
        </Kafka>

        <RollingFile name="rolling-file" fileName="${log-file-location}/app-core.log" filePattern="${log-file-location}/app-core-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${log-pattern}" />
        </Console>

        <FailOver name="fail-over" primary="kafka">
            <Failovers>
                <AppenderRef ref="rolling-file" />
                <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            </Failovers>
        </FailOver>

        <File name="internal-logs" fileName="${log-file-location}/app-core-internal.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${log-pattern}" />
        </File>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" includeLocation="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="fail-over" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="io.netty" level="INFO" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="internal-logs" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="io.vertx" level="INFO" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="internal-logs" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.mchange" level="INFO" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="internal-logs" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Since the application is built on vert.x when kafka cluster is down, all that I see is thread blocks and application doesn't respond and there are no other logs available across all the failover appenders configured. I'm using Log4j 2.13.0 and tested with even Log4j 2.14.1 which is the latest version at the moment.

Tried adding the `retryIntervalSeconds` attribute as well which didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It dosen't work because by default KafkaAppender ignores exceptions. From log4j2 KafkaAppender documentation

ignoreExceptions    boolean
The default is true, causing exceptions encountered while appending events to be internally logged and then ignored. When set to false exceptions will be propagated to the caller, instead. You must set this to false when wrapping this Appender in a FailoverAppender.

Set ignoreExceptions to false so the Appeder will know something is wrong and propagate the message to failover.