# Log4J Failover appender with Kafka doesn't work

Tags: log4j2

I am working on a Spring boot application that uses log4j and writes logs to Kafka. We have a failover mechanism to write logs to console when there are any issues in Kafka. I start the application when the Kafka broker is active and stop the broker after few minutes to see if logs are written to console. I do not see any application logs but just an error message stating "Unable to write to Kafka in appender". I tried the recommendation of "ignoreExceptions=false" in [Log4j failover for kafka appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499404/log4j-failover-for-kafka-appender/70428968#70428968), but still the logs are not written to console.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `ignoreExceptions="false"` in the configuration of KafkaAppender.

The default value of this is `true`, so log4j doesn't know anything if the appender goes wrong. By setting this value to `false`, log4j would know something wrong and propagate the message to the failover.